# How might one use the output parameters of `HashAlgorithm.TransformBlock`?

Tags: .net, api

The method [`HashAlgorithm.TransformBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock.aspx) takes the arguments `outputBuffer` and `outputOffset`.

I can't think of a reason for this method to have those. Is it so common to copy the hashed data somewhere that the copy was made an integral part of this method?

I'm rather curious to see a good use case involving these output parameters.

Comment: Additionally, the documentation doesn't mention that `outputBuffer` may actually be set to `null` to avoid the copy, and insists that "calling the `TransformBlock` method with different input and output arrays results in an `IOException`", which is not true.

Comment: API design at its best! So common in .net though...

Comment: Yeah, after looking through Reflector, I have no idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty clearly an oversight.  I couldn't find a source to back this up, but as it stands any use case we could imagine (I can't imagine any practical use cases) saves developers *at most* one line of code.  Worse, any developer who (for whatever reason) did want a copy of his own buffer made would probably find it so unlikely that `TransformBlock` would do this for her that she'd probably write that line of code herself anyway!

`outputBuffer` is used by other `ICryptoTransforms` in sensible ways (eg. *as an output buffer*), so it really should contain - when not null and not overwriting the input buffer - the intermediate digest, especially since it's not otherwise available from the class.  (Making the intermediate digest available is a nice idea whenever the input to the algorithm appears in multiple contexts.)

My guess is:

1. Someone got it backwards in [1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) regarding when the IOException should be thrown.
2. In [2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), someone "fixed" that problem, but misread the spec and copied from `inputBuffer` instead of `this.HashValue`.
3. Intermediate digests are used so rarely that no one has complained before [4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Oooh, right. It's because this implements an `ICryptoTransform` method, which was meant for things that produce outputs. I should have noticed that...

Comment: To make things worse, method summary in my IDE says, it is actually Hash which is written to output array. See this: http://i.imgur.com/W16YB.png

Comment: After reading this question and a blog post that shows using hashes with `CryptoStream`, it seems the intent was probably to make `HashAlgorithm` some kind of `tee`-like transform, that doesn't modify the data that goes through it but intercepts a copy of it for its hash.